# How to autocreate handlers for all events trough the XAML designer in VS2013

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I tried searching for this on the net but no result so far.

If I copy-paste a Window's XAML design from one Window to another I have a bunch of controls with written event handler names, but the event handlers themselves are missing in the code, as would be expected, so:

Is there a way to tell the XAML editor in Visual Studio 2013 to create automatically all event handlers that are missing in code-behind for the current Window?

Comment: That sounds somewhat dirty. Why do you need to copy alll that stuff? Is maybe an (abstract) base class a better solution?

Comment: You could run through each event and press **F12**, but if you're copying your events from another window, why would you need to? You can just paste the code in the code-behind. All that said however, there really is no real need to do this, you should really think about **inhertance**, as @ChrFin has already mentioned.

Comment: So the answer is No. Thank you. I am copying because I have several Windows with similar base structure. I am talking about copying the base layout panels, containing 4-5 events and after that mostly restyling them. It's not something huge, that I would need inheritance for.